# getting comma before first element in an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am inserting some data into an array but I am getting

```
,9,My firstname,My lastname,myemail@example.com,123456789
```

out in my console. How can I remove comma from first element i.e. 9? here is my code

```
var data = new Array();

                $(row_el.children("td")).each(function(i) {
                    var td = $(this);
                    //var data = td.html();
                    var td_el = td.attr('class');
                    //arr[i] = data;

                    if(!td.hasClass("element")) {
                        data[i] = td.html();        
                        console.log(i + ": " + data);
                    }

                });
```

I want output like this

```
9,My firstname,My lastname,myemail@example.com,123456789
```

then I will pass this array to a function and loop through this array.

Comment: It's quite likely that there is no comma in your first element; rather, there's an empty element before `9` in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `push()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) instead of setting to a specific position inside your array:

```
var data = new Array();

$(row_el.children("td")).each(function(i) {
    var td = $(this);
    //var data = td.html();
    var td_el = td.attr('class');
    //arr[i] = data;

    if(!td.hasClass("element")) {
        data.push( td.html() );        
        console.log(i + ": " + data);
    }

});
```

The problem is, that not all the elements in the array processed by `each()` result in an entry in your array. However, the index submitted to your callback (`i`) counts upwards nonetheless. So if there are some elements, that do not result in an entry to your array, these positions are filled with `undefined` (as long as you enter an element at a later position). These `undefined` entries now result in an empty string when outputting it the way you do, thus resulting to your leading comma.

Comment: Now I am getting this error in other function where I am passing this array `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object 9,My firstname,My lastname,myemail@example.com,123456789 is not a function `

Comment: I used both size() and length() functions to get the length of this array but both shows above error

Comment: `length` is not a function, it's a property. Use it like `data.length`

Comment: @al0neevenings As mentioned by Joy you access the length of an array by a property and not a function (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length))